# Eclipse - Exclude root directory from git repository?

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit

I'm trying to setup a git repository for my Eclipse project using EGit. However, I'm having trouble excluding the root/project directory from the repository. That being, my project has the structure:

```
ProjectDirectory
    src
    war
    etc
```

I would like the repository to contain `src`, `war`, and `etc`, but not contain the parent directory `ProjectDirectory`. That's because if I want to clone a copy of the project in my workspace, `ProjectDirectory2`, the repository for the second project now will try to create a second root directory, `ProjectDirectory`. Unfortunately, when I try to add a repository for a project using EGit, I seem to only be able to use Team > Share Project on the project folder itself and I don't seem to see anyway to exclude the root directory in the repository from within Eclipse.

Any suggestions on how to skip the top directory in the repository using EGit? I'd prefer being able to do everything from within Eclipse, but if there isn't a way, is there a way to setup the repository this way outside of git, then still be able to use the git control regularly from within git on the repository skipping the top level directory? Thank you much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should commit the project root for multiple reasons:

- If you commit only sub directories of your project, you will miss files and folders which are hidden below the project root (e.g. the .settings directory and others). Those need to be committed also, otherwise your project is going to miss information and may not lead to the same results on another machine.
- Your wish of trying to clone the same repository a second time in the same workspace sounds very much like you should re-read about git branches. In git, switching between branches is done after a blinking of the eye, so branches should be used when working on different features, versions or otherwise different editions of your project.
- The Eclipse project name and the underlying folder name on disk do not need to be the same (watch out for the checkbox "use default location" when creating a new project). So you can checkout a second clone of the project with a different name.
- If you later add more projects to your workspace (e.g. a test project), you cannot easily share them into the same git repository, as the content of those additional projects would mix up with the sub directories of the first project in the repository.

Comment: So I understand wanting to include sub-directories such as .settings, but these can still be included in the repository in the way I'm suggesting. I've also noticed that nearly every project I see online (such as on github) does exclude the top directory as I'm wanting to do (i.e. rather than projectRepository/projectFolder/src it's the repository on github just looks like projectRepository/src). Why do all these projects do it this way if the way your suggesting has advantages? Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I'd assume because they never had a test project. I've seen exactly that with an open source project where I contribute. We also committed only the sub directories and then created an additional repo for the test project. But pulling/pushing from/to multiple projects became so akwkward (and tests were not in sync with the main project), so we finally re-organized all code again and committed the project roots: https://github.com/cgeo/c-geo-opensource

Comment: If the project is using Maven and follows the Maven convention of having tests and resources in the same project, then you may be able to work easily with only the subfolders checked in. So you are right, it probably depends very much on the nature and layout of the project.

Comment: Isn't the different in the characteristic of the project? The project github.com/cgeo/c-geo-opensource is a typical eclipse project where you have multiple projects depending on each other (also in the eclipse workspace). But if you use Maven to organize your project (like : github.com/gwtbootstrap/gwt-bootstrap) it seems to be better to place the sources into the root like asked by golmschenk.

Comment: It's not just conventional to exclude the top level directory; it's *required* if your project is a PhoneGap/Cordova plugin.

Comment: the worst part is that there is no alternative to EGit in Eclipse... so we are stuck with this "feature" for years to come, it seems.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer is It is **POSSIBLE** with EGIT + M2E

trick is when doing share project -> in the configure git repo window

making sure use or create repository in parent folder of project is ticked

and making sure click create repository button

the main aim of this is to create the .git folder in you project root

not above your project root.

Comment: But if there is an existing project already created with a project folder under Git working tree, is it possible to remove the project directory?

Comment: This is the easiest solution, I was looking at another question for answers and deleted my local branch :(

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution. Though not particularly elegant - the steps are all simple, it works, and can be done in about 10 minutes:

1. Clone the remote git repo into your local filesystem .. e.g.:  `~/git/project_repo_root`
2. Create your eclipse project as usual .. e.g.:  `~/workspace/eclipse_project_root`
3. Delete the project from eclipse (but not filesystem!)
4. Open file manager and move the eclipse project you just created from ~/workspace/ root into ~/git

   `mv ~/workspace/eclipse_project_root  ~/git/`
5. Move the .git/ folder from the repo folder to the eclipse project root folder:

   `mv ~/git/project_repo_root/.git ~/git/eclipse_project_root`
6. Using a shell go into /eclipse_project_root/ and do the usual command line commands for all files you want in the repo:

   `git add <abc>; .. commit; .. push`
7. Return to Eclipse and go to Git Perspective, and click "Add an existing local Git repo to this view".  Select the git repo you are working with and the view should be updated with an entry for that repo once you say ok.
8. Once you see the local repo in your view, you can right click it and select Import Projects
9. Go back to your main development perspective (Java, etc) and you should see the project there with the Git markup on the root node in package explorer view.

~~~~~

At that point, you should see the eclipse project folder you had just moved *(to ~/git in the examples described here)*

I realize this is more verbose than I would like my answers to be, but for this particular challenge/solution .. I don't know of a more straightforward way to do it.

And as for the post above that describes you should always include the eclipse project root directory .. the reality is some projects/clients/etc require that the git repo not contain the root folder.  So a solution like this *is necessary* sometimes

Comment: in 10 minutes I can uninstall EGit and find a nice Git client to use :D

Comment: With this solution, the git project is in the same directory as the eclipse project. By default with EGit we have two separate directories, but it seems to be impossible to have this when cutting the project directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you have maven project you would typical like to create a repository without the project folder created by egit. For my experience this is not possible with the egit plugin.
But it can be easily done from the git command line.

First move your existing eclipse/maven project from your eclipse workspace into your git folder (this is what also the egit plugin did):

```
mv myproject ~/git/
```

next create a new git repository

```
cd ~/git/myproject
git init
```

Now create a .gitignore file and place it into your new repository folder (~/git/myproject/.gitignore). This is an example for a .gitignore file:

```
# ignore all bin directories
# matches "bin" in any subfolder
bin/

# ignore all target directories
target/

# ignore all files ending with ~
*~ 

# ignore eclipse directories and project files
.settings/
.project
.classpath
```

Finally initalize your new repository with the content of your project

```
git add *
git commit -m "My initial commit message"
```

Thats it. 
Now you can restart your eclipse and reimport the project from your new git repository.
Go into your eclipse egit repository view and coose 'import exisiting project'.

Comment: If the glob `*` matches any file in your .gitignore, `git add *` will fail.